# Particle variants after non-hangul script

Tags: particle

I am currently extracting the scripts from a game in all locales to aid my study while playing it (e.g. faster dictionary lookup). I am actually doing this to study Japanese but the completionist in me kinda wants to decode all the script-locales and there are special codes only used in the Korean version.

Apparently these codes dynamically print the correct variant of a particle depending on the previous character. These seem to be only used when the preceding word is also dynamic, e.g. a character's name the player can choose. So far I have identified codes for 은/는, 이/가, 을/를 and 으로/로.

<del>There is an additional code though that prints 이 after a consonant and nothing after a vowel. I read that 이/가 is sometimes dropped in casual speech but it still doesn't explain why only 이 would be used. One example where this is used:</del>

> <del>그래, 좋았어!</del>
> <del>`player-name` `particle`라면</del>
> <del>꼭 우승할 거야!</del>

<del>Would it make sense in this example to use 이 when the name ends in a consonant but drop 가 when it's a vowel? Also please keep in mind that I can't actually read this, I only know that the English version says "That's the spirit, `player-name`! Trust me—you can win this."</del>

Also, are there any specific rules for these particles when the preceding word is not written in Korean script or a placeholder-symbol? The game seems to use the variant that would be preceded by a vowel in these cases.

**Edit**
As pointed out in the comments, my first question was already answered elsewhere, I just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: _Possible_ duplicate of: [Is there a special meaning of '이' when added on to names?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/270/is-there-a-special-meaning-of-%EC%9D%B4-when-added-on-to-names)

Comment: Yes, thank you, that answers my first question.

Comment: How about after nasals like m,n,ng?  I would expect them to use the consonant variant.  For example, Ben, when written in Hangeul with a particle, would be "벤은", using the consonant variant.

Comment: @Michaelyus It’s only partially relevant. The suffix “-이” is usually only for _proper nouns_.  You don’t want to affix “-이” to the _common noun_ “Violin” like “Violin이” unless you’re making a nickname. It’s just that there’s two variations of particles “-이라면” and “-라면” for nouns with a final consonant and those without. The dictionaries list them separately. “Violin이라면“ is not a combination of “Violin,” “-이,” and “-라면.” It’s “Violin” and “-이라면.”

Comment: In short, it’s “`[PLAYERNAME][PARTICLE]`,” not “`[PLAYERNAME][PARTICLE]라면`.” The entire “-이라면” is a single particle.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. So here they coded only part of the particle then, a "partial particle" so to say. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Are there any specific rules for these particles—

These kinds of particles have two variants,

- one **for those with a final consonant** (e.g. “**잭**” — “은,” “이,” “을,” “과,” “-이다,” “-이면,” “-이라서,” “-이라면,” “-이고,” “-이었-,” “-이에요,” and “-아.”),
- and another **for those without** (e.g. “**사과**” — “는,” “가,” “를,” “와,” “-다,” “-면,” “-라서,” “-라면,” “-고,” “-였-,” “-예요,” and “-야.”).

**It depends on how the preceding word sounds when you read it.**

---

> ### —when the preceding word is not written in Korean script

You *completely* **transliterate it into Korean first** and pick the right particle variant accordingly. “Cat,” for example, becomes “캣” (or “캐트” by some speakers). It’s not “캩” because that’s just how the /t/ at the end usually gets transliterated by native South Koreans *nowadays*<sup>(I don’t know how the North’s doing on that.)</sup>. For that, South Korea has [the standard way of transliteration](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%99%B8%EB%9E%98%EC%96%B4_%ED%91%9C%EA%B8%B0%EB%B2%95), “외래어 표기법,” published by [the NIKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Korean_Language).

If you’re to append the particle “을,” the object marker, you write “Cat을” or “캣을” and read it as “캣을” (/캐슬/) with the /t/ sound disappeared, because **the Korean phonology applies as if it’s in Hangul.**

---

> ### —or a placeholder symbol?

**Which particle to use for a blank usually doesn’t matter.**

Write both variants of the particle

- “○은(는)” or “○은/는”
- “○이(가)” or “○이/가”
- “○을(를)” or “○을/를”
- “○와(과)” or “○와/과”
- “○(이)**다**” (or a bit rarely, “○이**다**/**다**”)
- “○(이)**면**” (or a bit rarely, “○이**면**/**면**”)
- “○(이)**라서**” (or a bit rarely, “○이**라서**/**라서**”)
- “○(이)**라면**” (or a bit rarely, “○이**라면**/**라면**”)
- “○(이)**고**” (or a bit rarely, “○이**고**/**고**”)
- “○이었다/**였**다” (You can’t group them by “었다;” “○(이)었다” doesn’t work.)
- “○이에요/**예**요” (You can’t group them by “에요;” “○(이)에요” doesn’t work.)
- “○아/야” or “○아(야)”

or just one of them, depending on how you’d like to read the blank ○.

- “○을”
- “○를”
- “○이”
- “○가”
- “○이다”
- “○다”

**How you read the blank is up to you.**

- “**뭐뭐**<sub>so-and-so</sub>를”
- “**무엇무엇**<sub>something-something</sub>을”
- “**아무개**<sub>Mr. or Ms. so-and-so</sub>가”
- “**누구누구**<sub>somebody</sub>가”
- “**무엇무엇**<sub>something-something</sub>이”
- or even literally, “**빈칸**<sub>blank</sub>이다,” “**동그라미**<sub>circle</sub>가,” or “**네모**<sub>rectangle</sub>였다,” because nobody cares.

[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #1]
[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #2]
[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #3]
[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #4]
[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #5]
[image: Fill-in-the-blank contest #6]

**But if it is supposed to be replaced with an actual word, you should have the following particle agree with that**. Though you could also go for the easy and lazy ways listing both variants (the most common way for applications) or sticking to one of the variants, it’ll look either *robotic* or *incorrect*. Just like “a(n) [PLACEHOLDER]” in English.

[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #1]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #2]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #3]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #4]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #5]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #6]
[image: A templated Korean sentence for simple substitution #7]

Doing this right is actually a pretty tricky, notorious challenge for programmers, known as “조사 처리<sub>dealing with particles</sub>.” They even write a whole library just to handle this. What makes it so difficult to do that correctly is the transliteration of non-Korean words, where the application has to know how to read them.

On top of that, just because a word ends with a consonant doesn’t mean it guarantees a final consonant in its Korean transliteration. “Wi**sp**” becomes “위**습**<sub>with a final</sub>,” “ca**ts**” becomes “캐**츠**<sub>without it</sub>,” “bee**r**” becomes “비**어**<sub>without it</sub>!” Wow, how consistent!

[image: Code to handle Korean particles]

Sophisticated applications would handle it properly by either

- **integrating such logic into themselves**,

  - “크레이지D(→크레이지**디**)**는** 무엇을 할까?” (“What will 크레이지D do?”)
    [image: A sophisticated one]
- or **carefully phrasing template sentences in a way that doesn’t require it**.

  - “모험가<sub>Adventurer</sub>!”
  - “[PLAYERNAME] 님<sub>-nim</sub>…….”
  - “[PLAYERNAME],<sub>comma</sub> ……!”

[image: -nim #1]
[image: -nim #2]
[image: Adventurer]

Comment: Wow, I hadn't expected such an extensive answer, thanks for all the insightful examples. I guess for the game I am analyzing they went with the lazy route. I just found out that internally the codes are called `Patchim` and the variants `original` and `patchim` (from パッチム I'd guess).

Comment: @hikidashi Yeah, apparently they gave up on the transliteration part and decided to just default to one of the `Patchim` (for those with a final consonant) version and the `Original` (for those without) version of the particles. Anyways, thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score -1):

> Also, are there any specific rules for these particles when the
> preceding word is not written in Korean script or a
> placeholder-symbol? The game seems to use the variant that would be
> preceded by a vowel in these cases.

If a non-Korean word is used, I think they'll assume a Korean pronunciation to add the particle after.  Since most foreign words ending in a consonant are transcribed and pronounced with a vowel after, then the particle that follows a vowel would be used.

For example, if the word is "Cat", then although in English, this word ends with a consonant, in Korean it would be transcribed "캐트" (ka-teu), ending in a vowel - and thus take a particle like 가/ga: cat가.

(The reason for this is that Korean consonants are unreleased at the end of a consonant.  Incidentally, recent variants of North American English often do not release final voiceless plosives, so that my English pronunciation of 'cat' is much closer to 캣 than 캐트, and is completely unreleased).

Comment: I think the tendency (as to how they transliterate non-Korean words internally to decide which particle to use) depends on the generation of the speaker. I suppose elder generations tend to append the “ㅡ (ŭ)” sound at the end. I would say “Cat(**캣**)이라면” /캐시라면/, “Cat(**캣**)이” /캐시/, and “Cat(**캣**)은” /캐슨/, **not** “Cat(**캐트**)라면” /캐트라면/, “Cat(**캐트**)가” /캐트가/, and “Cat(**캐트**)는” /캐트는/.